# gtest –– Undefined symbols when using TEST_F

Tags: c++, debugging, testing, linker, googletest

I am not sure if I setup my gtest environment correctly. When I do plain `TEST` with `EXPECT_EQ` stuff, it's all good. However, when I try fancier stuff like `TEST_F`, the linker complains.

Source Code:

```
class MyTest : public testing::Test
{
protected:
    static const int my_int = 42;
};

TEST_F(MyTest, test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(my_int, 42);
}
```

And this gives

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyTest::my_int", referenced from:
      MyTest_test_Test::TestBody() in instruction_test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [tests/tests/run_tests] Error 1
make[2]: *** [tests/tests/CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [tests/tests/CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [run_tests] Error 2
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not a problem from googletest, it is the semantic from C++.

The reason:
We can only call static class members on the class and not on an object of the class. And that is possible, even if no instance exist. That's why every static member instance must be initialize, usually in the cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

I managed solve the problem, but I don't know why it works this way:

So before I use `static const int my_int`, I have to declare it again outside of the MyTest class:

```
class MyTest : public testing::Test
{
protected:
    static const int my_int = 42;
};

const int MyTest::my_int;    

TEST_F(MyTest, test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(my_int, 42);
}
```

Comment: That is C++, it has nothing to do with Google tests. Any static class member from class declaration has to be instantiated (defined).